# Column color with jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have two questions:

1. How to color a column with jQuery DataTables?
2. How do I make column spanning with DataTables?

I'm using below code and would like to know with the same example. 
(I use JSON data to populate my table)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var resultArray = [
    ["290013", "TEST OF ENSEMBLE", "11-25-2016", "", "", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "2002", "XXX5", "XXX5", "XXX5", "", "1864", "2017", "VERSION", "23004746", "XXX5", "", "One Time", "", "", "", "", "", "", "21004482", "9189", "Feature Set", "20003880", "XXX5", "XXX5", "BASE", "19-APR-2017", "04-18-2017", "3877", "", ""],
    ["290015", "XXX5", "10-19-2016", "test", "$33.00", "22001204", "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT", "", "", "", "", "", "1865", "Deluxe", "EDITION", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "9190", "Charge", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
  ];
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [{
      title: 'Item Master Number',
      name: 'ItemMasterNumber'
    }, {
      title: 'Description',
      name: 'Description'
    }, {
      title: 'First Processing Date',
      name: 'FirstProcessingDate'
    }, {
      title: 'Alias',
      name: 'Alias'
    }, {
      title: 'Master Price',
      name: 'MasterPrice'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Id',
      name: 'ProductId'
    }, {
      title: 'Product Description',
      name: 'ProductDescription'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set#',
      name: 'FeatureSetId'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Code',
      name: 'FeatureSetCode'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Name',
      name: 'FeatureSetName'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Set Description',
      name: 'Feature Set Description'
    }, {
      title: 'Enablement Type',
      name: 'Enablement Type'
    }, {
      title: 'Feature Id',
      name: 'FeatureId'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Name',
      name: 'AttributeName'
    }, {
      title: 'Attribute Value',
      name: 'AttributeValue'
    }],
    data: resultArray,
    rowsGroup: [
      // Always the array (!) of the column-selectors in specified
      // order to which rows groupping is applied.
      // (column-selector could be any of specified in:
      // https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)
      'ItemMasterNumber:name',
      'Description:name'
    ],
    pageLength: '20',
  });
});
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/api/highlight.html

Comment: Can you please help me out with the colspan one.Is there any inbuilt config in datatables that would make it possible?

Comment: Sonali, **dataTables does not support colspans**!! I believe you have got that answer multiple times by now :)

Comment: @davidkonrad Is there any workaround or plugin available to achieve the same.The documentation says it does not even support rowspan but can be achieved via the rowsGroup plugin, is there a similar way for colspan too.

Comment: @davidkonrad I think if I am able to append some html to the table I'll achieve the output.My html will be the header.